# AWS Amplify iOS cognitoIdentityPoolNotConfigured error

Tags: ios, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-ios

I am using federated sign in using AWS Amplify SDK.
Following is my awsconfigfile.json

{
"UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
"Version": "0.1.0",
"IdentityManager": {
"Default": {}
},
"CredentialsProvider": {
"CognitoIdentity": {
"Default": {
"PoolId": "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Region": "us-east-1"
}
}
},
"CognitoUserPool": {
"Default": {
"PoolId": "us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
"AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"AppClientSecret":
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Region": "us-east-1"
}
},
"Auth": {
"Default": {
"authenticationFlowType": "CUSTOM_AUTH"
}
}
}

```
    let awsClient = AWSMobileClient.default()
    
    awsClient.federatedSignIn(providerName: Configuration.current.awsSAMLProvider,
                                              token: token) { (userState, error) in

        if let userState = userState {
            print("Status: \(userState.rawValue)")
            awsClient.getAWSCredentials { creds, error in
                if let creds = creds {
                    onComplete(.success)
                } else if let error = error {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried many things but always getting following  error
"There is no valid cognito identity pool configured in awsconfiguration.json."

Answer (score 0):

Adding initialization code in App Delegate fixed this issue

```
    AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
        
    }
```

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1773